# How $f(x)\le 0 \wedge f''(x)\ge 0 \implies f'(x)=0$?

Tags: real-analysis

According to Exc. 23 Sec. 4.3 of the book Advanced Calculus by Fitzpatrick,

> Let the function $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ have second derivatives and suppose that : $$ f(x)\le 0 \ \ \text{and} \ \ f''(x)\ge 0 , \ \ x \ \text{in} \ \mathbb R.$$ Prove that $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is constant.

It's easier to prove that $f'(x)= 0$ for all $x$ as it's logically equivalent to $f(x)= \text{const.}$. Well, of course $f'(x)$ is increasing. Nonetheless, $f'(x)$ can always remain negative even if it is strictly increasing. On the other hand, I can't find a counterexample; I tried $f'(x) = \tanh (x) -1 \le 0$, but it [doesn't](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph%20of%20ln%20cosx%20-%20x) result in a contradiction as $f(x) = \ln \cos (x) - x$. Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose there exists some $x_0$ such that $f'(x_0)\not=0$. There are two cases:

> $(1)f'(x_0)>0$.

In this case for all $x>x_0$ we have $f'(x)\geq f'(x_0)$, hence $f(x)\geq f'(x_0)(x-x_0)+f(x_0)$, which tends to $+\infty$ as $x\to+\infty$. A contradiction.

> $(2)f'(x_0)<0$.

The same idea applies. For all $x<x_0$ we have $f'(x)\leq f'(x_0)$, hence $f(x)\geq f'(x_0)(x-x_0)+f(x_0)$, which tends to $+\infty$ as $x\to-\infty$.

Comment: How $f'(x)>f'(x_0) \implies f(x)>f'(x_0)(x-x_0)+f(x_0)$? And even for $f'(x)<f'(x_0)$? Thanks

Comment: I don't mean geometrically; I mean an analytic proof.

Comment: By Lagrange's Mean Value Theorem $f(x)-f(x_0)=f'(\xi)(x-x_0)$ where $\xi\in(x_0,x)$. But for such $\xi$ we know  $f'(\xi)\geq f'(x_0)$. The case (2) is similar. Just note that $x-x_0<0$ combining with $f'(\xi)\leq f'(x_0)$ yields the same result.

Answer (score 1):

By using Taylor's Theorem: $f(x)=f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(x-x_0)+\frac{1}{2}f''(\xi)(x-x_0)^2$, where $\xi$ between $x$ and $x_0$. If the right side is not a constant, then it is a polynomial function and it can not be always nonpositive. Hence we get the contradiction.

Comment: "If the right side is not a constant, then it is a polynomial function" No it is not in general, since $\xi$ depends on $x$, hence your argument fails.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know anything about convex functions? The condition $f''(x)\geq 0$ means that $f$ is convex on $\mathbb{R}$. Let Then $f$ must lie above its tangent at $x=x_0$ that is:
$$f(x)\geq f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(x-x_0)$$
for every $x$ and $y$. It's easy to see that the condition $f(x)\leq 0$ for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$ is not satisfied unless $f'(x_0)=0$.

Comment: Yes, I know about convex functions, but I was trying to solve the problem without it since it is not introduced in the book yet ..

Comment: CaveJohnson showed how to get this inequality from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Sketch of proof: Suppose, for a certain $q \in \mathbb{R}$, $f'(q) = a > 0$. Then, since $f''(q) \geq 0$, $f'(x) \geq a > 0$ for all $x \geq q$. (If it would go to $0$ again, $f'(x)$ had to descent somewhere, but $f''(q)\geq0$). Hence, we can draw a line $l$ through $(q,f(q))$ with slope $a$, and we know that $f(x)$ should be above that line all the time. Since $a \neq 0$, it is not parallel to the $x$-axis and will therefore eventually cross the $x$-axis to go above zero. This is a contradiction

The proof for $f'(q) < a$ works similarly, yielding $a$ must be zero.

Answer (score 0):

I always like using Taylor's theorem to resolve questions of this kind (the information is about second derivative):

Fix any $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^1$, by Taylor's theorem with Lagrange remainder, for any $x \in \mathbb{R}^1$,
\begin{align*}
f(x) = f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(x - x_0) + \frac{1}{2}f''(\xi)(x - x_0)^2 
\geq f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(x - x_0)
\end{align*}
since $f'' \geq 0$. The remaining argument as @Cave Johnson then finishes the proof.

Answer (score 0):

$f"(x) >=0$   means slope is increasing everywhere or it is constant.

$f'(x) $ can be negative constant, but that would mean $f(x) $ crossing x-axis somewhere. And that cannot happen.
Slope cannot be positive constant.

Slope cannot increase anywhere, because $ f"(x) >=0$ makes  $f(x)$ monotonically increasing. And that cannot happen.
So $f'(x) $ should be zero.